# Diagnose WSUS "not applicable" update

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update

I have published a custom .msi application package to WSUS on Windows Server 2012 R2 using WSUS Package Publisher. The update is approved for a group of computers, some of which install said update without a problem (Windows 7 Client PCs). However, for a Windows 8.1 Client PC the update is shown as "not applicable". Executing the .msi package on this system manually works without any problem though, so it should definitely be applicable.

How can I diagnose why an update is marked as "not applicable" in detail? Is it possible to acquire logs for the "applicability decision process" performed by the Windows update client? (Note that `WindowsUpdate.log` does not contain any information regarding this update anymore). Is it possible to trigger this process manually?

The problem is specific to this manually published update, other updates are working as expected. The update in question is not superseded by another update.

Comment: Did you use a third-party tool to publish the package to WSUS?  If so, which one?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I used WSUS Package Publisher. I have edited the question.

Comment: Might just have been a glitch in the publishing process, I suppose; have you tried creating a new package for the same .msi ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston A new  package, created with the same options, did indeed work. Still no clue why, though. So I'd still like to find a way to debug the cause